# How to create table in mfc visual studio for excel?

Tags: range, worksheet-function, listobject

```
LPDISPATCH ListObjects::Add(long SourceType, const VARIANT& Source, const VARIANT& LinkSource, long XlListObjectHasHeaders, const VARIANT& Destination, const VARIANT& TableStyleName)
```

what to pass in each argument

```
XLS2007::ListObject Tblobj = oListObjs.Add( 1,COleVariant(range1), COleVariant((short)(0)),1,COleVariant(leftRange),COleVariant(oTblObj.tableStyle_Name));
range1 = "$A$1:$J$10;  
  
leftRange =  "$A$1"   ;
```

it gives the error code = -2147024809
its not able to create table for excel